# You don't have permission to access /frontend/web/ on this server

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos7

I deployed a Yii2 Advanced template application on a linux server with centOS and made the necessary permissions to the required folders. However, I am getting the error below:

You don't have permission to access /frontend/web/ on this server.

I have equally edited the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file under the `/var/www/html` to like

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Under the `/var/www/html/appFolder`, I have equally set AllowOveride to All but still not solved my problem.

Comment: have you changed mode /frontend/web to 777 or something else?

Comment: Yes I have changed it to 777 still no luck

Comment: maybe it's related to SELinux ?

Comment: This I have set the value to disabled and restarted the server, still no luck

Comment: What is the full file system path to your `frontend/web/` folder and what is the server's `DocumentRoot`?
Take a look into the `error.log`.

Comment: The full file system path is /var/www/html/appName and it is same with the DocumentRoot

Comment: Thank you. I later realized that PHP wasn't properly installed because when I tried an index.php file with echo statement, it was outputting the entire line. What I did was to remove and install PHP.